# What programming language to use for a form application?

Tags: forms, printing, scanning

I am planing on developing a software to fill out forms. The user will scan any form and then he or she will enter data in the form. Now I don't need OCR, just the ability to save the overlaying text the user enter in top of the form.

My question is what will be the best language to do this project?

Note: I am thinking that the project should be a desktop application, but should be able to connect to the internet to get information like forms scan by other users, etc.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat already does this.  How will your product differ from acrobat?

Comment: Beside the $1000.00 USD price tag, I plan to have a much simpler to use and a lot lower cost application. One simple thing Acrobat is missing on their form is the ability to store data in the file the same way Omniform does.

Comment: I think you can store data in the file (I don't know Omniform). I remember filling out forms in pdf and then emailing the file back.

Comment: Yes, but that is what omniform does it store the data of multiple forms input, so instead of having the same form fill 50 time and having 50 copies of the same form, omniform will home the 50 records on the same form file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not think about the language - think about the available libraries / drivers / etc. that you can use and also about the constraints of final users' environments. Language itself is a second choice.

Comment: For a long time I play with the idea to have as a web base application to have a more controlled environment, but it will require a subscription business model to make it work. I still haven't discard Adobe Flex for its easy to transition desktop to web feature, but you have a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Choice is yours - just look around and select the best tool to solve your problem.
In my opinion: if you think about standalone application for Windows with full set of accesible libraries easy to program - think about C# - its one of the best (effective) way to create software for mentioned purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I was actually thinking on Visual Basic. During my research I find out about Real Studio and one of the most compelling things it has is the option to export the same project on multiple platforms. Any comments on it?

Comment: If we talk about 'Real' programming language where you can control the code and it has to be multiplatform application - wise choice is java in tandem with Eclipse for example.

Comment: Yeah, I know of Java can do that, but I just don't like it (don't why). I am trying to find an application build on REAL Studio to test it and if I like it, I will make the jump.